# indexing algorithm to use for free form text

Tags: algorithm, text, full-text-indexing

I am tasked with working on an app to index free form text, for fast look-up. I am sure this is an area that has been researched to death. However I am not sure where to start, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's even an open-source tool that is well regarded.  http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Inverted index](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Inverted_index). There are a few implementations over the link.